# How can I save and restore a UIWebView to/from NSUserDefaults? (iOS 9)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, nsuserdefaults

I use the following code to create, save and restore a **UIWebView** to **NSUserDefaults**:

```
#pragma mark -

- (IBAction)create:(id)sender
{
    _webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    _webView.delegate = self;
    _webView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 20.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.width);
    [self.view addSubview:_webView];

    [_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"]]];

    NSLog(@"Created.");
}

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender
{
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [prefs setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.webView] forKey:@"webView"];

    [prefs synchronize];

    NSLog(@"Saved.");
}

- (IBAction)restore:(id)sender
{
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSData *data = [prefs objectForKey:@"webView"];

    _webView = (UIWebView *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
    _webView.delegate = self;
    _webView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 20.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.width);
    [self.view addSubview:_webView];

    NSLog(@"Restored.");
}
```

The delegate is also linked:

```
#pragma mark - UIWebViewDelegate

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    return YES;
}
```

Problem is, it's not working. The webView restored is just a white empty webView as if no restoration has taken place.

*Any suggestions?*

*Also, do you consider this a valid approach to handling **UIWebView** or am I going to have problems with submitting this to Apple?*

Comment: Why are you persisting a web view to `NSUserDefaults`? Why not just save the last URL so it can be reloaded?

Comment: I'd like to restore it with its history intact.